# Using cellphone batteries to build a big power bank

Tags: batteries

I'm working on a simple project where I'll purchase 8 rechargeable phone batteries, such as [these](http://dx.com/p/68706). I think the right way to hook them up if I want to double the voltage is to hook 4 in parallel, doing the same with the other 4, and then hooking these two groups in series. What I'm wondering is how will I be able to charge them. Has anyone ever worked on a project like this and/or done something similar? What's my best option to charge them?

Comment: It's far easier to buy and use either flat LiPo packs or 18650 Li-Ion cells.

Comment: The linked $3/1800mAh is a very good price for single quantities. Unfortunately you'll probably spend more on the charging..

Comment: Yes, there are easier ways out, but as @pjc50 said, this is the best bang for the buck. $2.50 (when you get 5+) per real ~1700mAh batteries. I've looked everywhere, I can't find a solution for charging the batch of them.

Comment: The price is great, but you need external circuitry as well. You typically can't hook up Lithium batteries in series or parallel without special considerations of how they will be charged/discharged. A lot of the packs come with circuitry built into the battery bank to handle this for you.

Also, I wouldn't connect them as 2 series strings of 4 parallel batteries, but rather 4 parallel banks of 2 series string batteries.

Answer (score 1):

One of these days I'll write a definitive Lithium charging article. Until then, I refer people to http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

You can get ICs that do one cell at a time, [which are about £0.50 each](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-battery-management/2556336?k=li-ion%20charger&quantity=1&ColumnSort=1000011&fid=0&pageSize=25). Two cells in series is more complicated due to the need to have a balancing connection in the middle.

Your best option is probably to find a charger designed for R/C car packs having cells in series, which will come with a balancing connection in the middle. Then build your 4+4 pack. Note that each cell should be at the same voltage before parallelling; connect them together first via 10R power resistors for a while to give them a chance to equalise.